# Stata coefplot with different axis range

Tags: stata

I am trying to create a coefficient plot that combines two models with the following command:

```
coefplot estimates_1_FR estimates_2_FR, bylabel(France) || estimates_1_UK estimates_2_UK, bylabel(UK)
```

Everything works well, except for the fact that the France estimates range between -0.02 and 0.03, while the UK estimates range between -0.2 and 0.3. For some reason Stata is using the x axis range as -0.2 0.3 for both models. I have tried adding xscale(range(-0.02 0.03)) after "bylabel(France)" but it does not work to change the axis range. Does anyone know how to change the axis range of each model?

Thank you!

Comment: `xscale()`  will **never** cause data to be omitted. This is documented under axis scale options.

Comment: I think this question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302285/how-to-specify-different-xscale-in-coefplot-using-stata